# Can a number input in Angular begin with a null value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

What is the correct way to have an Angular number input begin with a null value, and only have a value if the user enters one?

I have a `<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber">` in Angular. I want to initialize myNumber with a null value so it only has a value if the user enters one: `$scope.myNumber = null;`.  However a null value causes the error `Error: [ngModel:numfmt]`.

Comment: You could initialize the variable with an empty string and check if $scope.myNumber !== ''.

Comment: What about `undefined` ? Try it and if it works I'll post it as an answer. `$scope.myNumber = undefined;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a logical error to define the default value of null for number type. As explained here,

> The number input directive  requires the model to be a number.

Please refer the example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt?p0=guest) to use string to convert the string to number directive, using `ngModel.$parsers` and `ngModel.$formatters` in which case having null will also suffice